# PHP array syntax with [] versus {}

Tags: php

I am using PHP to work with an API that requires me to define arrays like this:

```
$array = [ "A" => [ [ "AA" => "Z" ], [ "BB" => "Z" ] ], "B" => "Z" ];
```

When I hard-code the values, no problem, but what would be the proper method to recreate this array structure with variables?

Something like:

```
$array = array('A' => array('AA' => 'Z','BB' => 'Z'),'B' => 'Z'); ?
```

Or should I be using curly braces or something else?

I need to be able to send a properly-formatted variable to the API instead of just hard-coding values.

Comment: There's no difference between using square brackets and using the `array()` function. You can use variables in both.

Comment: Curly braces aren't used for arrays in PHP.

Comment: "a properly-formatted variable to the API" sounds like you are looking for JSON - if that is what you need, then json_encode($array) will give you 'curly braces'....

Comment: Your two arrays aren't equivalent. In the first one, `A` points to a 2-dimensional array, in the second it points to one associative array.

Comment: @Barmar, actually, you can use curly braces for array access: https://3v4l.org/BZ7tp

Comment: @krlv But he's talking about creating arrays, not accessing them. The notation you showed is not recommended, I think it's just some ancient compatibility thing.

Comment: @krlv And AFAIK, that syntax is undocumented, I don't know if it's officially supported. It's more of a bit of trivia than anything else.

Comment: @Barmar True. Also, I hope it will be deprecated soon: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access

Answer (score 0):

`array()` and `[]` are equivalent, with the exception that short form is supported in PHP 5.4 or newer only.

Curly braces `{}` aren't related to arrays and it's completely different and should not be mixed.

Comment: As an 'odd note' (and what attracted me to this question) - just yesterday I was fighting an issue using only [] - the hosting company (HostGator) doesn't accept [] on their version (seems they modify it... :( PHP 5.4, 5.5 or 5.6......  We need to upgrade a client's server and go to 7.X but other software stops it - and the interem stuff uses [] which gives errors...... (AAARRRGGGHHHH!) so I may have to modify thousands of [] to array() just to be compatible with the hosting company! (yes, I recommended changing.... :)

Comment: I pretty much doubt anyone modified php to not support this feature as this would really be extremely stupid. And if you're right (again, I doubt that) then the last thing i would think of is to modify any of my software instead of moving to normal ISP with non broken PHP